# General integral of a differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this equation: $x^2y'+y^2-1=0$. It's an equation with separable variable. When I calculate the solution do I have to consider  the absolute value for the argument of the log?

Comment: Note that $\int \frac{dy}{1-y^2} = \tanh(y)+c$

Comment: So the solution is $\tanh(y)=-1/x+c$?

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac1{1-y^2}$$ is defined for all $y\ne\pm1$ and its antiderivative can be expressed as

$$\frac12(\log|y+1|-\log|y-1|)=\log\sqrt{\left|\frac{y+1}{y-1}\right|}.$$

Depending on the range of $y$, this function is one of $\text{artanh(y)}$ or $\text{arcoth(y)}$. Hence the solution to the ODE is one of

$$y=\tanh\left(C-\frac1x\right),\\
y=\coth\left(C-\frac1x\right)=\dfrac1{\tanh\left(C-\dfrac1x\right)}.$$

Notice that due to the singularities, the solution is not allowed to cross the values $y=\pm1$.

Also, these solutions are not defined at $x=0$. But then the original equation degenerates to $y=\pm1$ and the solution has a jump there. The cotangent solution is also undefined at $Cx=1$.

Comment: These "bad values" are not apparent from the differential equation except that we clearly see that after solving $x$ can't be zero thus $y$ can't be $-1$ for $\tanh$ e.g. (according to the standard theorem we are guaranteed a solution on some subset of the real line). Question: If the solution method produces a singularity at some point during the solution process, does that singularity *always* carry through to the solution?

Comment: @jdods: every step in the development must be justified. For instance, the transformation to the separated form is allowed only when $y^2\ne1$. After resolving this case, you still need to study $y^2=1$.

Comment: Due to the way the equation was originally written, there is not necessarily a problem at $y=\pm1$, hence we can extend the solution uniquely to the entire real line as 
$$y=\begin{cases}\tanh\left(C-\frac1x\right) & \text{ when } x>0\\ -1 & \text{ when } x\leq 0\end{cases}$$
when $x_0>0$ and $-1<y_0<1$ for example. Does this seem correct to you? Of course for different initial values, the $\coth$ solution also can be extended similarly.

Comment: @jdods: yep, $y=\pm1$ is a solution and the singularity at $x=0$ allows to switch from a solution to another.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I meant to write $\tanh^{-1}(y)$ in my comment, so the answer can be found as follows,

$$\frac{dy}{1-y^2} = \frac{dx}{x^2}\\
\implies\tanh^{-1}(y) = -\frac{1}{x} + c\\
\implies y = \tanh(c-\frac{1}{x})$$

Comment: It  I have the initial condition $y(2)=k$ for wich k the soluzioni is defined in $(0,+\infty)$?

Comment: You didn't address theOP's question related to the range of $y$. For this reason, your solution enforces $|y|<1$, and is incomplete.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: @GiuliaB.: read my answer.

Comment: But how can i find k?

Comment: @GiuliaB.: $k$ is given.

Comment: I have to find k so the solution is in $(0,+\infty)$

Comment: That's not possible as a solution can only be valid in one of 3 intervals $(-\infty,-1)$, $(-1,1)$, $(1,\infty)$. Unless you mean $x \in (0,\infty)$, then it doesn't matter what $k$ is

Comment: the solution of the book is $-\frac{e+1}{e-1}\le k\le1$